# CSS3PIE: Internet Explorer 6 doesn't download PIE.htc

Tags: internet-explorer-6, css3pie

I'm using the very impressive CSS3PIE (http://css3pie.com) library to add support for CSS3 styles in IE6-8. It works fine in versions 7 and 8 and took a lot of pain out of the process.

However, in IE6 no CSS3 styles are shown at all. In fact, looking at the server logs, I can see that IE6 doesn't even download the PIE.htc file, which is necessary for the magic to work. The content type for the file is set correctly as text/x-component, it's referenced by absolute URL, and works fine in IE7 and 8.

I'm using Compass (www.compass-style.org) and the PIE helper which makes the CSS look like this:

```
#shopping_cart {
  behavior: url("/media/static/css/PIE.htc");
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. Does anyone have any ideas what might cause IE6 to skip the behavior definition altogether?

Cheers,

Jonas

Comment: CSS3Pie works well for me, including in IE6. But we've dropped support for IE6 in our site anyway so it doesn't matter for us. Given that IE6 now has only about 2% market share, and falling, it's getting to the point where I really wouldn't get too hung up on it. I know that doesn't answer your question, but its the way I feel. Be happy you've got it working in IE8, but IE6 just isn't worth the hassle any more.

Comment: That's exactly the way I feel... unfortunately not our customer. It's an ecommerce site with an older and not particularly computer-savvy customer base, ~5% of which still use IE6.

Comment: @Jonas - I'd argue that rounded corners are superficial enough that IE6 users can live without them if the rest of the site works. But I'm realistic: I know what its like to have fixed requirements and have to stick to them, so I do want to help. It's very hard to help here though because there's nothing wrong with your code (as evidenced by it working in IE7/8), and PIE definitely does usually work in IE6 with the same code. Could you provide a link to your site, or an example that demonstrates the problem? That may help with the diagnosis.

Comment: @Jonas - Also, have you asked the question on the PIE website? The author is very good at responding to difficult questions like this.

Comment: I've never had this problem with CSS3Pie, always been really straight forward. I found this though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907510/solved-ie6-png-transparency-css-hack-not-working - seems unlikely but you could try it out :)

Comment: @Spudley: Thanks for your feedback, what I really need from CSS3PIE is the PNG transparency it provides and I don't really want to include another hack for that. Without transparency, the site really looks awful. I did ask on the author's site (who really is very responsive) but I guess the weekend isn't working in my favor here. :-)

Comment: @lnrbob: Thanks, that did help me find a couple of new google searches to try. No gold yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

See if the information on this question is helpful:

[CSS3 PIE - Giving IE border-radius support not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522145/css3-pie-giving-ie-border-radius-support-not-working/)

Answer (score 0):

I just had a coworker run into a similar problem in IE8 - he was getting a permission denied error in the DOM inspector because he was trying to test it on the local machine.  Putting it up on a dev server and testing from there solved the problem.  Probably not the same issue here, but posting it anyway in case it helps other users.

As for IE6 in general, I usually tell people it's not worth paying extra to have everything look identical in IE6 especially when it's such a superficial visual issue and so few people use it.  Pixel perfect rendering across browsers is not nearly as important as being functionally consistent.  That said, if you want to pay me $200 an hour (double my rate because it's such a PITA and a waste of time), go right ahead - it's your money. ;-)